# how to make a vertical list items the same height?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the items in a vertical list the same height. Like this? [image]

However, I am having problems making the items the same height. So far I have created this:
[image]

following code snippet can give an overview of what I am trying to achieve.

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

ul#sectors {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul#sectors>li {
  background: #08455C;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul#sectors>li>p {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <ul id="sectors">
    <li>
      <p>All</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Business <br>Support</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Creative</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Cybersecurity</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Engineering</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Finance</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Hospitality</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Information Technology</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Misc.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Sales</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Technical</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/XxmVRN

Comment: **Do they have to have the same width ?**
because that is highly inefficient of using horizontal space as you can see some of the words don't that much space.
one way is to prevent word wrap and add padding without defining any width.
[check this](https://jsfiddle.net/2b59cLfn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` to `ul` instead `display:inline-block` to `li`

```css
html{
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

ul#sectors{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left:0;
  display:flex;
}

ul#sectors>li{
  background: #08455C;
  color:#fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:10px; 
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

ul#sectors>li>p{
  margin:20px 0;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<ul id="sectors">
  <li><p>All</p></li>
  <li><p>Business <br>Support</p></li>
  <li><p>Creative</p></li>
  <li><p>Cybersecurity</p></li>
  <li><p>Engineering</p></li>
  <li><p>Finance</p></li>
  <li><p>Hospitality</p></li>
  <li><p>Information Technology</p></li>
  <li><p>Misc.</p></li>
  <li><p>Sales</p></li>
  <li><p>Technical</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ul` CSS with following CSS

```
ul {
display: table-row;
}
```

And `li` CSS

```
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```